# Why does System Monitor show so many File Systems?

Tags: filesystem, system-monitor

When I opened System Monitor for the first time just after installing, it only showed three or four records, now after a week it shows a bunch of them, some 100% full. What does that mean?

[image: System Monitor > File Systems screenshot showing many /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root and /dev/loopXX entries]